# Infinite loop in A* algorithm

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to understand the A* algorithm. I wrote by examples, but often it gets into an infinite loop.
What is the problem?
Please forgive me for the English language.

Path Search Code:

```
public Node GetPath(Vector2 goal,Vector2 start) {
  List<Node> OpenNodes = new List<Node>(); //список с не просмотренными узлами
  List<Node> ClosedNodes = new List<Node>(); //список с не просмотренными узлами

  OpenNodes.Add(new Node
  {
      pos = start,
      parent = null,
      DistStart = 0,
      DistOnGoal = GetDistOnGoal(Vector2.zero, goal)
  });

  while (OpenNodes.Count > 0) {
      var FirstNode = OpenNodes.OrderBy(node => node.FullDist).First();
      ClosedNodes.Add(FirstNode);
      OpenNodes.Remove(FirstNode);
      if (FirstNode.pos == goal) {
          Debug.Log("путь есть");
          return FirstNode;  
      }

      foreach (Node n in NighBours(FirstNode, goal)) {
          var chanel = false;
          foreach (Node d in ClosedNodes) {
              if (n == d) {
                  chanel = true;
                  continue;
              }           
          }
          if (chanel)
          {
              chanel = false;
              continue;
          }
          var opennod = OpenNodes.FirstOrDefault(node => node.pos == n.pos);
          if (opennod == null)
          {
              OpenNodes.Add(n);
          }
          else {
              if (opennod.DistStart >n.DistStart) {
                  opennod.DistStart = n.DistStart;
                  opennod.parent = FirstNode;

              }
          }
      }
  } 
  return null;
}

public float GetDistOnGoal(Vector2 n, Vector2 goal) {//дистанция до цели 
  return Mathf.Abs((goal - n).magnitude);
}

public List<Node> NighBours(Node n,Vector2 goal)//соседи
{
  var Point = new Vector2[4];
  var Nodes = new List<Node>();
  Point[0] = new Vector2(n.pos.x - 1, n.pos.y);
  Point[1] = new Vector2(n.pos.x + 1, n.pos.y);
  Point[2] = new Vector2(n.pos.x, n.pos.y + 1);
  Point[3] = new Vector2(n.pos.x, n.pos.y - 1);

  for (var i = 0; i < Point.Length; i++)
  {
      if (Point[i].x > 1 && Point[i].x < map.GetLength(0) - 2 && Point[i].y > 1 && Point[i].y < map.GetLength(1) - 2)
      {
          if (map[(int)Point[i].x, (int)Point[i].y] == 0)
           {
              Nodes.Add(
                new Node
                {
                    pos = Point[i],
                    parent = n,
                    DistStart = n.DistStart + 1,
                    DistOnGoal = GetDistOnGoal(Point[i],goal),
                });
          }
      }
  }
  return Nodes;
}

public class Node {
  public Vector2 pos;
  public Node parent;
  public float DistStart;
  public float DistOnGoal;
  public float FullDist
  {
    get
    {
        return DistStart + DistOnGoal;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the node code.
The function never returned null, although an example of this implies.
Debug also can't because Unity hangs tight

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the beginning of your method and see what append

Comment: Your `chanel` variable is useless. The only time it is ever true, you hit a `continue` which goes back to the top of the loop where the variable is immediately set to false.

Comment: `OpenNodes.Count` still > 0 with more of one node. I don't see where you remove nodes `OpenNodes`, just the first and after !? I see you add node `OpenNodes.Add(n);` but not removing anything.

Comment: You might rather simply want to use a [`Queue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1) instead of a list here

Comment: @Shim-Sao `OpenNodes.Remove(FirstNode);`

Comment: If the loop is infinite, you add more than you remove. Print the count in the loop to see its value.

Comment: @Draco18s I Fixed, did not help